# Angular2 - What folder for custom CSS / JS files?

Tags: angular

I have to include a set of CSS and JS files in my angular2 application.

What is the correct folder in order to have them included **when I do the build**?

Should I have to put them inside **SRC\Assets** or under **SRC\myFolder** ?

Once defined it, how do I have to include them inside my app.component.html and how to configure `<base href="/">` properly?

Thanks to support

Comment: put them in your assets.

Comment: What are you using for building the application? Webpack, perhaps?  You could have a look for best practices at the [AngularClass/angular-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) repo in github. Will give you some clues on how things are being done right now :)

Comment: I just do "ng build --prod"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using the Angular CLI then you can put them anywhere, but I would suggest in a logical place that makes sense in your src/assets folder.

From there add entries for the js and css files in your angular.cli.json file.

there is a scripts array and a styles array under each object/app in the apps node.

look for something like ...

```
apps: [
 {
   ...
   "styles": [ "assets/styles/myCustomStyles.css" ],
   "scripts": [ "assets/js/dragevents.js" ]
 }
]
```

If done correctly the cli will automatically add them to your index when it builds.

Answer (score 1):

I am using webpack and in my application, I have placed them in src/assets folder now I can just use it like this

```
<img class="photo-icon" src="/assets/img/user-default.png">
```

You can make separate folders for javascript, images and stylesheets etc. in your assets folder and append in the path.

Comment: Abdul under assets folder, the CSS/JS are rendered properly but the image no. Can u help me ?

Comment: Is it giving 404 error ? Can you see the image if you open the image url in new window ?

Comment: No I cant see the image... I try to access it by direct url "http://localhost:4200/assets/distAdminLte2/img/icon-user.png" and I can't reach her, if I instead I try to load a css like "http://localhost:4200/assets/distAdminLte2/css/AdminLTE.min.css" , it works

Comment: using <img src="src/assets/distAdminLte2/img/icon-user.png"> it works but I think I will face some problem once I build the solution for production...

Comment: I have used it in production too with java spring and it works without any problem.

Comment: Thanks Abdul, I will open a new question providing all the details

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking where to put the styles the official angular style guide says:

https://angular.io/styleguide#!#05-04

it is a recommended way, but as the comment bellow you can put them in the order that makes better sense for you.