# problem adding template,s css and JavaScript file on angular

Tags: angular

I have several css and JavaScript file on my angular assets folder. Now I need to add those with angular to work.I have tried to link the css and js in my html file like

```
assets/css/example.css
```

but it is not working..

how can I properly add my css and js on my angular app.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438206/angular2-what-folder-for-custom-css-js-files

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare those files in angula.json under  "styles": [ and "scripts": [
ref -: https://www.floxblog.com/add-external-css-javascript-file-in-angular/